# How can I stack images vertically in a div

Tags: css

I want a div containing three images and I'd like the images stacked vertically.
I've set the div width to the width of my images and that doesn nothing.  Here's my code:

```
.detailImgWrapper
    {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    top:-210px;
    }

.detailImgWrapper img
    {
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: inline;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    }
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: can you send link to an example using jsfiddle.net . I don't understand why setting display:block for your img tags doesn't accomplish what you want (as suggested by Aaron).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set your images to `display: block`, and they should stack vertically.

Comment: I thought so too.  When I do that, the line break is applied to the entire window, not just within the div.

Comment: If I change the img to display: block it seems like that also gets applied to the containing div.

Comment: @jblasco Thanks for the jsFiddle.  I modified it to produce my exact problem.  I want the div containing the three vertically stacked images to be to the right of the other (35x35) div I created here. http://jsfiddle.net/QqJRR/1/  I can only solve one or the other of these problems, not both at the same time.  Thanks.

Comment: This can be achieved by using `float: left` http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/QqJRR/2/ or `display: inline-block` http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/QqJRR/3/

Comment: Good thinking, @jblasco, just remember that if you're going to use the `inline-block` method, you should set the `vertical-align` property to `top` to achieve the same effect as the floating blocks. (http://jsfiddle.net/QqJRR/4/) Also, inline-block won't work on some older browsers (namely IE6), so floating blocks are probably your best choice. Just remember to place a clearing element below your floating divs to force their parents to acknowledge their height.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of parent with display:inline and child as display:block is a technique I use to arrange elements horizontally with dimension. Display:block is necessary to give dimension (i your case padding).

The code you have written appears to be working towards lining-up the images horizontally rather than stacking them vertically. So, I wonder what function the display:inline is serving in the parent?